# SQL select query for getting new line seperated rows

Tags: sql

I have rows in the table as below.

[image]

Need SQL select oracle query which gives Items as new line delimited text.

Output needed as below.

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

Comment: " new line seperated text" ... ????

Comment: What do you mean new line seperated? SQL return rows . So what do u mean ? Please rephrase your question and perhaps add what you tried so far.

Comment: New line seperated mean, a new line delimiter between A and B.

Comment: You do not do it in your `sql` but in your programming language of choice say `php` for example.

Comment: do you want it to display as string? loop all the record get in select and concat it there

Comment: you mean to say like A is in one row then skip the second row and B in third row and so on ..

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of oracle, you can use one of these aggregation functions:
http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php